# JS Replace String starting with space and ending with space or comma or dot with another string

Tags: javascript, regex

I know basic Javascript Regex. But I am confused with lookheads. As the title says, I want to replace a word with another word if it ends with `space`, `dot(.)` or `comma(,)`
For Eg: Replacing `"his"` with `"her"` in the following Text

```
"XYZ his this his, his."
```

to

```
"XYZ her this her, her."
```

Comment: What are you confused at? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Something of this kind replaceAll(" her(?![a-zA-Z])"," him",string);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
input.replace(/\b([hH])is(?=[., ])/g, '$1er')
```

---

Lookahead is a zero width assertion which would only **check** but not **match** the input..

With above regex you are matching `his` only it is followed by `[., ]`..

`\b` is a word boundary which would let you match individual words..

Comment: Thanks! Also what if I want to cover the case for "His" by "Her"?

Comment: You can change `h` to `[hH]` in regex

Comment: @emotionull see the edit..basically am capturing H or h in group and then backreferencing in replace

Comment: That's awesome. Will definitely upvote after getting reputation points to do so.

Comment: Just add a quote(') before $1er